# add a array of keys in mongodb doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
{
    'cr':[
              { key: 'key1' },
              { key: 'key2' }
         ]
}


function addCriteriaKey(id, key, callback) {
    var options = {new: false, select: '_id'};
    if (typeof key === 'string') {
        Model.update({'uid': id}, {'$addToSet': {'cr': {'key': key}}}, options, function (err, data) {
            if (err) callback(err, null);
            else callback(null, data);
        })
    } else if (typeof key == 'object' && (key instanceof Array)) {
        Model.update({'uid': id}, {'$addToSet': {'cr': {'key': {'$each': key}}}}, options, function (err, data) {
            if (err) callback(err, null);
            else callback(null, data);
        })
    }
}
```

what this method does is to add key into the 'cr' filed, if the key is a string, add it directly, if the key is a array of string, then add them all by suing the '$each' command

Adding a string works pretty well, the problem rises when adding to a array of string, I expect it could add one by one, but the result is different 
For example:
addCriteriaKey('id',['111','222','333'],function(err,data){})

My expected result :

```
{
    'cr':[
              { key: '111' }, { key: '222' }, { key: '333' }              
         ]
}
```

However the result is :

```
{
    'cr':[
              { key: {'$each':{'111','222','333'}} }           
         ]
}
```

I wondered what is the problem for this?

Answer (score 0):

either we can do in this way,

```
Model.addNotiCriteriaKey( 5, [{'key':'111'},{'key':'222'},{'key':'333'}], function(err,data){})
```

or using underscore to sort out array into key-value arrays

```
    Model.addNotiCriteriaKey( 5, ['111','222','333'], function(err,data){})
    function(id,key,callback){
        _.map(key, function(element){ return {'key':element}; });
        UserModel.update({'uid':id},{'$pull':{'cr':{ '$each': key}}},options,function(err,data){
            if(err) callback(err,null);
            else callback(null,data);
        })
}
```